# C++ dll cant locate C# dll when called from java using jni

Tags: java, c#, c++, dll

I have created a C# class that using an external dll as a dependency. I need to call the generated dll from C# from java. I have then created a C++ class that add the C# dll and its depandacy which work fines within visual studio. The problems comes when I call the c++ dll from java. The JVM crashes because the c++ dll cant locate the C# dll dependancy but have already put all the three dlls(C#dll,C#dependancy dll and cppdll) in src folder of java project which have created using eclipse. My question is how can I make the C++ dll locate the C# dll and its depandancy in java.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, you have a dll used by a c# project, and you created a c++ project referencing the c# dll? And then this last c++ dll is referenced by java, right?

Comment: @Phate01 yes the c++ dll(which references the C# dll) is now called from java using jni. which makes the JVM to crash

Comment: Do you have any specific error/exception to show?

Comment: #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (0xe0434352), pid=2848, tid=5868
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b147
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x812f]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows